# MIPS string control not work fine

Tags: mips

Hello everybody friends :) I coding an exercise but I have found a problem and in two days I haven't found the solution... I explain better, this is my code:

```
main:
#first message
la $a0, m1
li $v0, 4
syscall

#space in the stack
addi $sp, $sp, -41

#read the input
move $a0, $sp
li $v0,8
li $a1, 41
syscall


#bge $a0, 41, error
...
```

My code, read 40 characters (41 with string terminator)to count the vocal letters inside a string and, if I insert 41 characters send me an error message and repeat the stamp of the menu and the relative input, where is the problem? If I use this code without the control -->  bge $a0, 41, error --> everything works fine, I can insert 1-40 characters with and without a space, when I insert this control give me the error that I have set when the string is 40+ character (see below to understand better)

Example with control:

- input: hello(click return) ERROR: the string is bigger then 40 character
- input: h ello(click return) ERROR: the string is bigger then 40 character

Any help or advice is the welcome :)

Thank you all, have a nice day!

P.s.
Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

`bge $a0, 41, error` makes no sense here. System call 8 doesn't return a result, it just stores the characters into the buffer you supplied it with. If you want to find out the number of characters that were written to the buffer, loop over the buffer until you find a byte with the value 0 (or possibly 13 [carriage return]).

Answer (score 0):

Friend maybe I have solved my problem... this is my solution I hope that it is good

```
#Create two copies of the string, one for nectCh and another for contaVocali
move $t0, $a0
move $t2, $a0


nextCh:
        # extract a character from the string
        lb $t1, ($a0)

        # check the end of the string, so if it is more than 40+1
        # give me the error message and repeat the prompt and the input
        beq $t1, $zero, error

        #check the carriage return and go to the function
        beq $t1, 10, contaVocali

        #next character
        addi $a0, $a0, 1

        # repeat
        j nextCh
```

Is acceptable like solution?

Thank you

P.s.
The output is accordant with the output proposed on the exercise ;)